# std::vector::insert, is it ok to call it with end as first parameter?

Tags: c++, stl

As for the title, is it ok to pass `vec.end()` as the position parameter? I.e., is the behaviour of

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.insert(vec.end(), 0);
```

well defined?

Comment: Yes, probably, but I'd use `push_back` instead

Comment: @Robert: You can't insert a range though with push_back `vec.insert(vec.end(), begin, end);`

Comment: @StefanoFalasca: You can only push back one element at a time onto the end of the vector. `std::vector::insert` can be used to insert a range of elements at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is well defined. Assume if vector is empty, `begin()` equals to `end()`. The effects is it inserts a copy of element before iterator.

§ Table 100 — Sequence container requirements (in addition to container)

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|a.insert(p,t)  | iterator    Requires:T shall be CopyInsertable into X. For   |
|               |             vector and deque, T shall also be CopyAssignable.|
|               |             Effects: Inserts a copy of t before p.           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

also look at: [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the iterator passed to insert functions gives the position *before* which the new element is inserted. Inserting at `end()` thus makes an element the last one in the container.